# iOS push notification sound doesn't cancel on open

Tags: ios, audio, apple-push-notifications

I am creating an application that uses Apple Push Notifications with custom sound (about 15 sec length). If I open notification when phone is in use, sound terminates, but if I open notification when it wakes up phone from sleep mode, sound continues to play until the end. How can I avoid unnecessary push sound playing?

Comment: Considering the sound is played by the system I'd be surprised if you could control that. I don't know if this would work but you could try playing a silent sound when your app is opened, it just might stop the other sound.

Comment: @SomeGuy, I already have tried that. Another sound plays together with the push sound until the end of the push sound file

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is quite late, but it turns out that apple does not provide any API to manage push notification sounds, so you can’t stop it from playing. I would like to suggest you use shorter push notification sound. This also makes sense because intent of push notification is to shortly inform user about new event, not disturbing him for a long time.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but how for example Skype app do that when user receives a call while app in background? I need the same functionality

Comment: There is an API for stopping notification sounds. You do so by removing the notification from Notification Center.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 10, you can remove all notifications from Notification Center by calling

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
```

The audio stops playing, but all the notifications are removed from Notification Center.

Alternatively, to stop the sound for only a specific notification, you can use:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeDeliveredNotifications(withIdentifiers: [String])
```

This stops the audio for only the given notifications, and removes them from Notification Center.

To get the ids for all the delivered notifications, use

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications { notifications in
  let ids = notifications.map { $0.request.identifier }
}
```

Of course, the downside is that the notifications are removed from the user's Notification Center.